# Twilio Invalid TLS protocol in vb.net

Tags: ssl, twilio

Since a few days I can't send text messages from my application made with vb.net. When debugging I get this error
Twilio says Invalid TLS protocol

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the documentation here?

[Tips for Upgrading Your Environment to Support Twilio REST API’s TLS and Strong Cipher Suite Changes](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006751753-Tips-for-Upgrading-Your-Environment-to-Support-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Strong-Cipher-Suite-Changes)

Comment: Not recommended since it doesn’t address the issue but you should be able to disable the TLS 1.2 requirement in Twilio console until you address the underlying issue.